# Determining parameters for distribution of standard deviations

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation, chi-squared-distribution

I have a database of 10-star movie ratings (similar to IMDB),
with a large number of movies and an also large number of ratings
for each movie.  For each movie I have computed the mean and stddev
of its ratings.  Now suppose that movie ratings are normally distributed
(in real life they are not, but bear with me).  I want to know the
type of distribution and the distribution parameters that the **stddevs** follow.  Now, after some googling it seems these should
be follow a Chi-squared distribution, but I'm having some trouble
calculating its parameter from the raw data I have (I'm not a statistician).  Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If your movie ratings, call them $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are all independent and identically distributed as normal random variables $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then

$$\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi_{n-1}$$

where $s^2 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}$. Or you could also say

$$s^2 \sim Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2}, \frac{2 \sigma^2}{n-1})$$

If you are assuming each movie has a different normal distribution of ratings, then you have to estimate each standard deviation separately.

When you calculate the sample standard deviation, you're done. That's the estimate for $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The Chi-squared distribution is used to create confidence intervals of the sample standard deviation and run statistical tests. However, it isn't the distribution of the sample standard deviation itself. This link describes the distribution you're looking for.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html

The density is given by $f_N(s)$. It uses these variables, and all formulas are given:

1. N: the number of ratings
2. $s$: the biased estimator of standard deviation
3. $\sigma^2$: the unbiased estimator for the variance.

However, this formula looks to be derived assuming the data is Normally distributed. It looks like from Wikipedia, [standard deviation estimators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Unbiased_sample_standard_deviation) (and therefore distribution) will change depending on the distribution of the data.